# c# Linq to sql - the class element is not assigned

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, invalidoperationexception

I've got a PCL with a class BaseRootUser

```
public class BaseRootUser : IUser
{
    public virtual int RootUserID { get; set; }

    public virtual int TypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual int ClinicID { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

and a Serverproject with this class:

```
[Table]
public class RootUser : BaseRootUser {

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public override int RootUserID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public override int TypeID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public override string Username { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public override string Password { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public override int ClinicID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public override bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get a RootUser out of the Database like this:

```
public static RootUserController Get(DataContext db, int baseUserID) {

        try {
            IQueryable<RootUser> query =
            from rootUser in db.GetTable<RootUser>()
            where rootUser.RootUserID == baseUserID
            select rootUser;

            RootUser ru = query.Single<RootUser>();
            return new RootUserController(ru);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Globals.MessageController.CreateMessage(ex.ToString(), colour: ConsoleColor.Red);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The line **RootUser ru = query.Single();** throws an **InvalidOperationException** telling me *the class element **BaseRootUser.Username** is not assigned*. Original message: *System.InvalidOperationException: Das Klassenelement "BaseRootUser.Username" ist nicht zugeordnet.*

```
bei System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaType.GetDataMember(MemberInfo mi)
bei System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetKeyFromPredicate(MetaType type, Dictionary`2 keys, Expression mex, Expression vex)
bei System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetKeysFromPredicate(MetaType type, Dictionary`2 keys, Expression expr)
bei System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetKeyValues(MetaType type, LambdaExpression predicate)
bei System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(Expression query)
bei System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetCachedResult(Expression query)
bei System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
bei System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
bei System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

If I remove the Property **Username** from the base, it works as expected.
Is this a Bug or did I do something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

## Edit

Interesting: this works

```
IQueryable<RootUser> query =
from rootUser in db.GetTable<RootUser>()
select rootUser;

var all = query.ToList();
var ru = all.Where(u => u.Username == username).FirstOrDefault();
return new RootUserController(ru);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it with FirstOrDefault() and the same thing happens. By the way: there is one Database record with UserName **Daniel.Martin** and I am looking for exactly this string.

Comment: You will get an "InvalidOperationException" if any of these following critera matches in the .Single method: 
No element satisfies the condition in predicate. 
-or- 
More than one element satisfies the condition in predicate. 
-or- 
The source sequence is empty.  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534800(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2
if you put a breakpoint on the LINQ-statement, is the **Username** the only thing that is empty?

Comment: Well the query shows this: *{SELECT [t0].[RootUserID], [t0].[TypeID], [t0].[Username], [t0].[Password], [t0].[ClinicID], [t0].[IsDeleted]
FROM [RootUser] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Username] = @p0
}*
Or do you meant something different?